# Origin domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jsonp, access-control

Getting the "Origin http://domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. " error. what I am trying to do is I have a newsletter system I set up on a subdomain and the newsletter on another subdomain. The code works fine when a user inputs an incorrect email and also submits the info, however it will not display the, "success, email sent message" and I am getting the error when submission is made.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        var ap = $('.appear-first:eq(0)').fadeOut(200);
        if ($('#email').val() === '' || $('#email').val().search('@') == -1){
            ap.css('color','#f00').text('Please enter a valid Email Address.').fadeIn(300);
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {

            var a = $('#subscribeform');
            console.log(a);
            $.post('http://domain.domain.com/?p=subscribe&id=1', a.serialize(), function(re) {
                console.log(re);
                ap.css('color','#fff').text('Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will be emailed shortly to confirm your address.').fadeIn(300);

            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

The browser will send a pre-flight request to check if the requested domain allows `CORS` by checking the response headers.

The domain you are requesting to should know about the domain you're requesting from.

So on `domain.com` implement something like this (PHP example):

```
$allowed_domains = array("http://sub.domain.com");

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
  && in_array($allowed_domains, $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

    // emit CORS header
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    // enable session/cookies
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // optional headers here
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "OPTIONS") {
    // CORS pre-flight request, we don't need to do anything else
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when using the code you provided I am getting the script over written and its inputting all the values on the newsletter page which is seprate from the other subdomain. Which I was able to get last time. However, I am not getting the 2 messages(error please input correct email, and thank you for submitting messages) Is there another work around?

Comment: Also like I said it is functioning the way it is suppose to however it will not display the thank you once the email is submitted, but it is going through to the newsletter system.

Comment: That sounds a bit too detailed, I don't know how your subscription service works. Did this solve your CORS problem though?

Comment: yes, however it forwards to the domain where the subscription form is. What I needed is it to confirm that the email sent with the thank you for sub. message

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that. There are several solutions in varying amounts of complexity and security.